# Modify web.config with powershell

Tags: powershell, web-config, connection-string, powershell-3.0

I need to try to update a web.config file to change the IP address only of the web.config
I have included the section of code Im looking at for powershell to script the change.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionString" connectionString="provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=192.168.1.100;database=sample;Trusted_Connection=Yes" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    <add name="sqlConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.100;Initial Catalog=sample;Trusted_Connection=Yes" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I would like a very simple solution to this
just update the ServerIP address.

Anyone know an easy way to do this with PowerShell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd to the following

```
$cfg = [xml](gc web.config)
# Replace all references of the IP in all connection string
$cfg.configuration.connectionStrings.add|%{
   $_.connectionString = $_.connectionString -replace "192.168.1.100", "1.0.0.1";
}
$cfg.Save("Web.config");
```

If you are just looking to replace a specfic connection string, I'd fetch it like this:

```
$con= $cfg.configuration.connectionStrings.add|?{$_.name -eq "SqlDataCon"};
# Replace the content
$con.connectionString = $con.connectionString -replace "192.168.1.100", "1.0.0.1"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try :

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content c:\temp\web.config)
$conString = $xml.connectionStrings.add[0].connectionString
$conString2 = $conString -replace '192.168.1.100','10.10.10.10'
$xml.connectionStrings.add[0].connectionString = $conString2
$conString = $xml.connectionStrings.add[1].connectionString
$conString2 = $conString -replace '192.168.1.100','10.10.10.10'
$xml.connectionStrings.add[1].connectionString = $conString2
$xml.Save('c:\temp\web2.config')
```

This do the job for the two connection strings. If you don't want to hard code the old IP address you can use :

```
$conString -replace 'Server=.*;','Server=10.10.10.11;'
```

Comment: For me I had to make the regex non greedy otherwise it would erase any of the keys after Server: $conString -replace 'Server=.*?;','Server=10.10.10.11;'