# Powershell: Updating IIS web.config

Tags: asp.net, powershell, iis, ssl, cookies

Needing to update IIS web.config to secure cookies by adding SSL.

Web.Config currently contains the following snippet.

```
<configuration> 
  <system.web> 
       <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
       </authentication>
  </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

Wanting to update system.web section as follows.

Need to modify (Assume you would use Set-WebConfiguration)

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
to
<authentication mode="Forms" requireSSL="true">
```

Need to add (Assume you would use Add-WebConfiguration

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" />
```

Have used the following successfully to update web.config,

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath "iis:\Sites\FMC" -filter "/appSettings" -name "." -Value @{key='fmcDataContextType';value='SqlRepository.fmcDataContext'}
```

But can't seem to get the right format for this purpose.

Comment: [see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827324/modify-web-config-with-powershell)

Comment: Both answers for the question you link to modify the XML directly. That is not recommended because there is no schema validation and by changing the XML you could break your web site.

Comment: @Peter-Hahndorf Both changes have been tested successfully and are recommended.  If not changing in this manner, for a large farm, how would you suggest otherwise?

Comment: FredrickCampbell - I'm not saying they are not working and if you are very careful modifying the XML directly can work, but what if you mispell the name of an attribute, your script works perfectly fine, but the site would be broken. There is an COM API for changing the IIS configuration. And there are wrappers for it in WMI, managed code, PowerShell and also appcmd.exe. Oh I'm talking about Lloyd's link, not your question. I noticed I forgot the @lloyd

Comment: @Peter-Hahndorf thanks for the feedback, trying out your solution. Your solution works well +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **requireSSL**:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.web/authentication/forms" -name "requireSSL" -value "True"
```

for **httpOnlyCookies** use:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.web/httpCookies" -name "httpOnlyCookies" -value "True"
```

for adding **httpOnlyCookies** use:

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty  //system.web 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site' -Name httpCookies -Value "True"
```

you have to replace `Default Web Site` with the name of your site.

Comment: Ahh, that's the ticket.  Thanks!